# How to implement notifysetDatachanged method in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i have a listview which contain some data from server and for this i am using json and also implemented adapter.notifyDataSetchanged() but i want to know whether i am doing in a write way or not pls check.

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ARRAY);// GETTING DEAL LIST
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                            m_VcomData = new CVcomStorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                            m_VcomData.setmDealTitle(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_NAME));//getting deal name
                            m_VcomData.setmDealCode(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_CODE));// getting deal code
                            m_VcomData.setmDealValue(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_VAlUE));
                            m_VcomData.setmDescription(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_DETAILS));
                            m_VcomData.setmDealActionUrl(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ACTION_URL));
                            String logo = post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_LOGO);
                            m_VcomData.setmIcon(imgPath + logo);
                            if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
                                Log.d(m_kTAG, "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                            if (BuildConfig.kMonkeyInfo)
                                Log.i("Monkey", "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                            if (!s_VcomDataSet.contains(item)) {
                                s_VcomDataSet.add(m_VcomData);
                                m_VcomAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    m_VcomAdpter = new CVcomAdapter(HomeScreenActivity.this, s_VcomDataSet);
                    mVcomListview.setAdapter(m_VcomAdpter);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to write `m_VcomAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();` outside of the `for` `loop` because it will call again and again util your loops count.

2nd thing if you are creating or initalizing adapter after your api call then you don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

So directly call this after `for` `loop`

```
     m_VcomAdpter = new CVcomAdapter(HomeScreenActivity.this, s_VcomDataSet);
     mVcomListview.setAdapter(m_VcomAdpter);
```

3rd thing if you modified your array then you can call like

```
m_VcomAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

e.g.

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ARRAY);// GETTING DEAL LIST
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                            m_VcomData = new CVcomStorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                            m_VcomData.setmDealTitle(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_NAME));//getting deal name
                            m_VcomData.setmDealCode(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_CODE));// getting deal code
                            m_VcomData.setmDealValue(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_VAlUE));
                            m_VcomData.setmDescription(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_DETAILS));
                            m_VcomData.setmDealActionUrl(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ACTION_URL));
                            String logo = post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_LOGO);
                            m_VcomData.setmIcon(imgPath + logo);
                            if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
                                Log.d(m_kTAG, "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                            if (BuildConfig.kMonkeyInfo)
                                Log.i("Monkey", "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                            if (!s_VcomDataSet.contains(item)) {
                                s_VcomDataSet.add(m_VcomData);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    m_VcomAdpter = new CVcomAdapter(HomeScreenActivity.this, s_VcomDataSet);
                    mVcomListview.setAdapter(m_VcomAdpter);
```

Answer (score 0):

notifyDatasetChanged() used for update the ListView item.

Suppose you have deleted or added something in your list in your case "s_VcomDataSet".

you should use notifyDatasetChanged() that reflects new changes in data and notifies ti listview.

For better usability you should use RecyclerView in place of listview

Answer (score 0):

You should set the adapter before calling notifyDatasetChanged() on it. Your code should be along following lines-

```
   CVcomStorage m_VcomData = new CVcomStorage(); 
    m_VcomAdpter = new CVcomAdapter(HomeScreenActivity.this, s_VcomDataSet); 
mVcomListview.setAdapter(m_VcomAdpter);

        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ARRAY);// GETTING DEAL LIST
                            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                                    // object create of DealAppdatastorage
                                    m_VcomData.setmDealTitle(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_NAME));//getting deal name
                                    m_VcomData.setmDealCode(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_CODE));// getting deal code
                                    m_VcomData.setmDealValue(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_VAlUE));
                                    m_VcomData.setmDescription(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_DETAILS));
                                    m_VcomData.setmDealActionUrl(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ACTION_URL));
                                    String logo = post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_LOGO);
                                    m_VcomData.setmIcon(imgPath + logo);
                                    if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
                                        Log.d(m_kTAG, "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                                    if (BuildConfig.kMonkeyInfo)
                                        Log.i("Monkey", "Logo Path::" + item.getS_szicon());
                                    if (!s_VcomDataSet.contains(item)) {
                                        s_VcomDataSet.add(m_VcomData);
                                        m_VcomAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
```